# Remove random index from an arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an ArrayList of 4 items. I need to remove one item randomly and display the updated ArrayList. However my random keeps targeting the second and third element on the array list. As far as I understand my random would count like this: 0 1 2 3. Shouldn't that be enough to cover my 4 elements? Why does it keep targeting the same indexes? I have tried increasing the random number (4) + 1, but that puts me out of bounds.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfGuests = 4;
ArrayList<String> guestList = new ArrayList<>(4); 
System.out.println("Enter 4 guests:");

for(int i = 1; i <=numberOfGuests; i++){
    System.out.printf("guest%d: ", i);
    guestList.add(input.nextLine());
}
System.out.println("Guest List: " + guestList);
String remove = guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4)); 
System.out.printf("%s can't come%n" , remove);   
System.out.println("Guest List: " + guestList);
```

Comment: Your code copied as is works for me locally in IntelliJ.

Comment: Your code works for me. I've ran your code on coderpad using 4 predefined guests a, b, c and d. I am running it 10 times and you can see that it works. the link is here: https://coderpad.io/FPNDM4CD

Comment: You know what fellas, my bad. I had to run it  more than 15 different times to get all of the values, the random just happened to keep choosing the same elements for the first 5 times i ran it.

Comment: How can i delete this question, or close it? Before it gets massacred with down votes.

Comment: Don't worry about it, you posted completely functional, well thought-out code.  As you can see, nobody has downvoted it yet.  You can just delete it.

Comment: Thanks for running it , i noticed you turned it into a static method and used it to run it on main 10 times using a for loop, why dint i think of that. I kept running it manually and comparing results. silly me.

Comment: I guess you don't even have to delete your question. It's well formed and if anybody has trouble with removing random elements from an `ArrayList` themselves they can refer to your question and see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

yoy check when you user random number generation the rage is set to length of array  minus one such as in your case

```
String remove = guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(3));
```

Comment: `nextInt(n)` already checks the range from `0` to `n` **exclusive**. So your answer would only check indices `0 - 2` which is not correct. And btw, OP already said that his code works as intended.